# Nginx: proxy localhost webapps for both 80 and 443 not working

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy, openssl, docker-compose

I have this problem. I have two web apps running on docker with docker machine and an **nginx** container for the reverse proxy.

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
networks:
  default:
    ipam:
     config:
       - subnet: 10.5.0.0/16
         gateway: 10.5.0.1
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.13
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    ports: 
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
    volumes: 
        - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
        - ./nginx/ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl
        - ./nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
    networks: 
        default:
            ipv4_address: 10.5.0.2

  webapp1:
    build: webapp1
    container_name: webapp1
    environment:
      - JVM_OPTS=-Xmx12g -Xms12g -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
      - CATALINA_OPTS=-Xmx12g -Xms12g -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
      - JAVA_OPTS= -Ddb.url=db_url.com -Ddb.port=3306 -Ddb.username=test -Ddb.password=test
    ports: 
        - "8080:8080"
    depends_on: 
        - nginx
    networks: 
        default:
            ipv4_address: 10.5.0.3
  webapp2:
    build: webapp2
    container_name: webapp2
    environment:
      - JVM_OPTS=-Xmx12g -Xms12g -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
      - CATALINA_OPTS=-Xmx12g -Xms12g -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
      - JAVA_OPTS= -Ddb.url=db_url.com -Ddb.port=3306 -Ddb.username=test -Ddb.password=test
    ports: 
        - "8081:8081"
    depends_on: 
        - nginx
    networks: 
        default:
            ipv4_address: 10.5.0.4
```

And this is my nginx.conf:

```
server {
        # Listen on port 80 and 443
        # on both IPv4 and IPv6
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ipv6only=on ssl;

        # if ($scheme = http) {
        #   return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        # }

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx-cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx-cert.key;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;

        location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        location /webapp1 {
            proxy_pass https://10.5.0.1:8080/webapp1;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            client_max_body_size 20M;
        }
        location /webapp2 {
                proxy_pass https://10.5.0.1:8081/webapp2;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
                client_max_body_size 20M;
            }
```

But Nginx seems not working. The resulting page returns, with url **http://localhost/webapp1**, a **400 Bad Request The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port**. 
From url **https://localhost/webapp1** I have always a **403 Forbidden**.

From nginx logs:

http://localhost/webapp1

```
nginx                | 10.5.0.1 - - [05/Sep/2018:12:31:18 +0000] "GET /webapp1 HTTP/1.1" 400 674 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.81 Safari/537.36" "-" nginx                | 10.5.0.1 - - [05/Sep/2018:12:31:18 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 400 674 "http://localhost/webapp1" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.81 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

For **https://localhost/webapp1**:

```
nginx                | 10.5.0.1 - - [05/Sep/2018:12:32:51 +0000] "GET /webapp1 HTTP/1.1" 403 572 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.81 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx                | 2018/09/05 12:32:51 [error] 7#7: *21 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 10.5.0.1, server: , request: "GET /webapp1 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://10.5.0.1:8081/webapp1", host: "localhost"
nginx                | 2018/09/05 12:32:51 [error] 7#7: *21 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 10.5.0.1, server: , request: "GET /webapp1 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://10.5.0.1:8081/webapp1", host: "localhost"
nginx                | 10.5.0.1 - - [05/Sep/2018:12:32:51 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 572 "https://localhost/webapp1" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.81 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

With the other web application is the same.

The ssl certificates are self-signed certificates generated with openssl.

Anyone can help me? Really thanks